# Cant figure out how to get the code to display the item in the room

Tags: python, text-based

I am creating a text-based game for my Python class and I can't get it to display the item when entering the room. I can collect it, and the inventory gets displayed. Just not the item that is in the room. I have put in the code I am using currently, I have tried adjusting it but then I get errors thrown at me.

```
# Welcome message to the player
def prompt():
    print("\t\t\tWelcome to professional wrestling!\n\nVance McMan has locked all wrestlers into an evil "
          "contract.\n\n"
          "You must collect all 6 items and defeat Vance to free all the wrestlers.\n\n"
          f"To move:\t'go {direction}' \n\
          \t 'get item name' \n\n")

    input('Press any key to continue...')


# clear the screen after the welcome message
def clear():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')


# dictionary
rooms = {
    'Ring': {'North': 'Gym', 'South': 'Steel Cage', 'East': 'Dressing Room', 'West': 'Office', 'Item': 'Chair'},
    'Office': {'West': 'Ring', 'Boss': 'Vance McMan'},  # villain
    'Gym': {'South': 'Ring', 'East': 'Garage', 'Item': 'RKO Promo Video'},
    'Garage': {'West': 'Gym', 'Item': 'Blueprint'},
    'Steel Cage': {'North': 'Ring', 'East': 'Greenroom', 'Item': 'Mr.Socko'},
    'Green Room': {'West': 'Steel Cage', 'Item': 'StoneCold Beer'},
    'Dressing Room': {'East': 'Ring', 'North': 'Locker Room', 'Item': 'Rics Robe'},
    'Locker Room': {'South': 'Dressing Room'}  # starting room
}

# list of vowels
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

# directions
direction = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']

# track inventory
inventory = []

# track the current room
current_room = 'Locker Room'

item = rooms[current_room].get('Item')
# results of the players previous move
msg = ''

clear()
prompt()

# gameplay loop until exit
while True:
    clear()
    # display info to player
    print(f"You are in the {current_room}\nInventory : {inventory}\n{' - ' * 27}")

    # display the msg
    print(msg)

    # indicate items
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
        nearby_item = rooms[current_room]["item"]

        if nearby_item not in inventory:

            if nearby_item[-1] == 's':
                print(f'You see {nearby_item}')

            elif nearby_item[0] in vowels:
                print(f'You see an {nearby_item}')

            else:
                print(f'You see a {nearby_item}')

    # boss encounter
    if 'Boss' in rooms[current_room].keys():
        # lose
        if len(inventory) < 6:
            print(f"Game over! You lost a fight with {rooms[current_room]['Boss']}")

        # win
        else:
            print(f"You beat {rooms[current_room]['Boss']}")

    # accept the player move as input
    move = input('Which direction will you go?\n')

    # split the move into words
    next_move = move.split(' ')

    # the first word is an action
    action = next_move[0].title()

    if len(next_move) > 1:
        item = next_move[1:]
        direction = next_move[1].title()

        item = ' '.join(item).title()

    # move in between rooms
    if action == 'Go':
        try:
            current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]
            msg = f'You go {direction}.'

        except:
            msg = f'You cannot go that way.'

    # picking up items
    elif action == "Get":
        if item == rooms[current_room]['item']:

            if item not in inventory:
                inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
                msg = f"{item} retrieved!"

            else:
                msg = f"You already have the {item} in your inventory."

        else:
            msg = f"Cannot find the {item}"

    # exit the game
    if move == 'Exit':
        current_room = 'exit'
        print('Game over. Thank you for playing!')
        break

# any other commands invalid
else:
    msg = f"Invalid command"`
```

Comment: `if 'item' in rooms[current_room].keys():` is never true because the key you have used for the item is `'Item'`, not `'item'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among several other issues, when you're splitting on the user's input command, you need to add a `maxsplit` so that the second portion of the string can contain spaces unmodified.

```py
rooms: dict[str, dict[str, str]] = {
    'Ring': {'north': 'Gym', 'south': 'Steel Cage', 'east': 'Dressing Room', 'west': 'Office', 'item': 'Chair'},
    'Office': {'west': 'Ring', 'boss': 'Vance McMan'},
    'Gym': {'south': 'Ring', 'east': 'Garage', 'item': 'RKO Promo Video'},
    'Garage': {'west': 'Gym', 'item': 'Blueprint'},
    'Steel Cage': {'north': 'Ring', 'east': 'Green Room', 'item': 'Mr.Socko'},
    'Green Room': {'west': 'Steel Cage', 'item': 'StoneCold Beer'},
    'Dressing Room': {'east': 'Ring', 'north': 'Locker Room', 'item': 'Rics Robe'},
    'Locker Room': {'south': 'Dressing Room'},
}


def prompt() -> None:
    print(
        '\t\t\tWelcome to professional wrestling!'
        '\n'
        '\nVance McMan has locked all wrestlers into an evil contract.'
        '\n'
        '\nYou must collect all 6 items and defeat Vance to free all the wrestlers.'
        '\n'
        f"\nTo move:\t'go [north | south | east | west]'"
        "\n\t 'get item name'"
    )


def indicate_item(room: dict[str, str], inventory: set[str]) -> None:
    nearby_item = room.get('item')
    if nearby_item is not None and nearby_item not in inventory:
        vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
        if nearby_item[-1] == 's':
            print('You see', nearby_item)
        elif nearby_item[0] in vowels:
            print('You see an', nearby_item)
        else:
            print('You see a', nearby_item)


def encounter_boss(room: dict[str, str], inventory: set[str]) -> bool:
    boss = room.get('boss')
    if boss is None:
        return False
    
    if len(inventory) < 6:
        print('Game over! You lost a fight with', boss)
    else:
        print('You beat', boss)
    return True


def describe_turn(room_name: str, inventory: set[str]) -> None:
    print(
        f'\n{" - " * 27}'
        f'\nYou are in the {room_name}'
    )
    if inventory:
        print('Inventory:', ', '.join(inventory))


def go(room: dict[str, str], direction: str) -> str | None:
    next_room = room.get(direction)
    if next_room is None:
        print('You cannot go that way.')
        return None

    print(f'You go {direction}.')
    return next_room


def get_item(item: str, inventory: set[str], room: dict[str, str]) -> None:
    if item in inventory:
        print('You already have the', item, 'in your inventory.')
    else:
        if room.get('item') == item:
            print(item, 'retrieved!')
            inventory.add(item)
            del room['item']
        else:
            print('Cannot find the', item)


def main() -> None:
    prompt()
    inventory = set()
    room_name = 'Locker Room'
    
    while True:
        room = rooms[room_name]
        describe_turn(room_name, inventory)
        indicate_item(room, inventory)

        if encounter_boss(room, inventory):
            break

        match input('Which direction will you go? ').split(maxsplit=1):
            case 'go', direction:
                room_name = go(room, direction.lower()) or room_name

            case 'get', item:
                get_item(item, inventory, room)

            case 'exit', :
                print('Game over. Thank you for playing!')
                break

            case _:
                print('Invalid command')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
            Welcome to professional wrestling!

Vance McMan has locked all wrestlers into an evil contract.

You must collect all 6 items and defeat Vance to free all the wrestlers.

To move:    'go [north | south | east | west]'
     'get item name'

 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
You are in the Locker Room
Which direction will you go? go south
You go south.

 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
You are in the Dressing Room
You see a Rics Robe
Which direction will you go? get Rics Robe
Rics Robe retrieved!

...

-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
You are in the Office
Inventory: StoneCold Beer, Blueprint, RKO Promo Video, Mr.Socko, Rics Robe, Chair
You beat Vance McMan
```